# С++ Рекурсия

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, есть задача

> Лесенкой называется набор кубиков, в котором каждый более верхний слой содержит кубиков меньше, чем предыдущий. Требуется написать программу, вычисляющую   число  лесенок, которое  можно построить из N кубиков.
>
> Входные данные
>
> Во входном файле INPUT.TXT записано натуральное число N (1 ≤ N ≤ 100) – количество кубиков в лесенке.
>
> Выходные данные
>
> В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT необходимо вывести число лесенок, которые можно построить из N кубиков.

С Рекурсией столкнулся в 1 раз, погуглил понял что это, но как подойти к этой задаче не знаю, напишите в общих чертах, как все организовать. Спасибо.

P.S. не прошу полностью делать все за меня, задание не учебное (не лаба какая-нибудь)
Вот [Линк](http://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=16) на оригинал.

И еще в задаче имеются в виде не ступеньки, а количество вариаций лесенок, то есть если дано 6 кубиков то есть 4 варианта: 6, 5+1,4+2,1+2+3.

Comment: Я не уверен, что эта задача решается рекурсией. Вы пробовали аналитически её решить? Может выводиться зависимость?

Comment: Чтобы понять рекурсию, нужно сперва понять рекурсию.

Comment: Мне нужно именно рекурсией(что бы ее освоить), а задача рекурсией решается( судя по заголовку в оригинале задачи).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот рекурсивная функция:

```
int stairs(int n)
{
    int i,out;
    if(n<=2) return 1; // 1 или 2 кубика можно разложить только 1 способом
    out=0;
    for(i=0;i*2<=n;i++) // Меняем i от 0 до половины n
    {
        // Отделяем от кучи i кубиков и смотрим сколькими способами их можно разолжить:
        out += stairs(i);
        // Если отделили ровно половину, то убираем из подсчета случай, когда n раскладывается на два слоя одинаковой ширины:
        if(i*2==n) out--;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Со вводом-выводом думаю разберетесь.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде работает, попбробую теперь разобраться в вашем коде, для меня он  выглядит совершенно не понятно.

Comment: а еще можно хранить все уже посчитанные значения функции `stairs`, чтобы не считать лишний раз

Answer (score 1):

1. получаем число - количество кубиков
2. вызываем метод подсчёта линий
3. получаем результат

в самом методе

1. приняли значение
2. минусанули 1 от него
3. плюсанули к кол-ву ступенек
4. вызываем сами себя, рекурсивно
5. получили на выходе результат

Comment: А что если main функцию сделать рекурсивной?Или это глупость?

Comment: да, вряд ли у тебя такое получится =)

Comment: сразу оговорюсь, мой вариант - неправильный по условиям задачи, так как он не считает ВСЕ расклады лесенок (можно же просто взять все элементы минус 1 - первая ступенька, и 1 - вторая)

Comment: Рекурсивный main() ?  Это легко:

    main (int ac, char **av, char **ev)
    {
      if (ac > 0) {
        printf("%d\n",ac);
        main(--ac,av,ev);
      }
      return 0;
    }

Comment: @username76 у меня ошибку выдаёт